# Reduce Hash Match Cost in sql code

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have two tables and I am finding the missing values that exist in the second table but not in first table.

Below is my sql code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Patient
   ,B.Visit
FROM ( SELECT Patient
           ,Visit
           ,VisitName
        FROM dbo.PatientVisit
     ) A
   ,( SELECT Visit
           ,VisitName
        FROM dbo.Visitlookup v1
    ) B
WHERE B.Visit NOT IN ( SELECT Visit
                        FROM dbo.PatientVisit p1
                        WHERE A.Patient = p1.Patient )
    AND B.Visit <> A.Visit
GROUP BY A.Patient
   ,B.Visit
HAVING B.Visit <> MAX(A.Visit);
```

Explaining my code...

I have two tables one for patient visit and another the visit lookup. I have patient visit from 10 to 70 in the look up table.

Some patients have missed visits in there regular schedule. Say a patient has come for visits 10, 20 , 30, 60 and 70. So 40 and 50 will be there missed visits.

I want to return patients who has missed visits. So I had the patient data having Patient and Visit as Query A and Data from lookup table as Query B. Then i'm taking visits from lookup table that does not exist in Query A. This will give me the missed visits.

The code is working fine and i want to optimize the code. When I checked the execution plan, I found that Hash Match is taking up 46% cost of overall execution.

Below is my execution plan screenshot.

[image: Execution Plan]

Is there a way to optimize this code so that the performance can be better?

I have the schema and data in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5824).

**Updated**

I found the reason why hash match takes more cost. Its due to

A Hash Match is likely to pop-up in the following scenarios:

- No covering index is available on the tables involved in join, union
  or aggregation operations.
- One large table is being joined against a    much small table, Hash
  Match sometimes proves to be very efficient in    these cases.

As users suggested I created constraints and modified the code.

I created covering index on the patient visit table for visit as included columns and got some changes on the cost. The Hash Match reduced to 20.5% from 46% however the sort operation got a little bit cost from 26% to 37%. but the overall cost came down to 41%

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what your query does? It's so complicated it's hard to read (and probably the reason it's slow)

Comment: Hi Amit, I have updated my question including what my query does.

Comment: Looking at the SQL fiddle, why are you using `float` type to identify patients and visits? Also, your fiddle is missing primary keys.

Comment: Also, your tables do not seem to be normalized. You have `VisitName` in both `Visitlookup` and `PatientVisit` tables.

Comment: That's my client data which i dont have access to modify.

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman: What part can you not modify? The PKs/contraints? The types? You should at least suggest to change/fix this.

Comment: Yes, The constraints and types. I can suggest but dont know how far it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need sub-query for tables `dbo.PatientVisit` and `dbo.Visitlookup`, and `cross join` also can be replaced by `INNER JOIN`. Also, you can replace `NOT IN (SELECT FIELD FROM ... WHERE {Condition}))` with `NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ... WHERE {Condition})`.

So, I suggest that finally must be something like this:

```
SELECT  A.Patient ,
        B.Visit ,
        MAX(A.Visit)
FROM    dbo.PatientVisit AS A
        INNER JOIN dbo.Visitlookup AS B ON NOT EXISTS ( SELECT    NULL
                                                  FROM      dbo.PatientVisit p1
                                                  WHERE     A.Patient = p1.Patient
                                                            AND B.Visit = p1.Visit )
                                     AND A.Visit <> B.Visit
GROUP BY A.Patient ,
        B.visit
HAVING  B.Visit <> MAX(A.Visit)
```

---

with your data sample you will not see the difference, but if you will increase your dataset several times, you will see this execution plan:

*SSMS reflection of the Execution Plan:*

[image: SSMS Actual execution plan]

*SQL Sentry Plan Explorer reflection of the Execution Plan:*

[image: SQL Sentry Plan Explorer]

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same execution plan for your code.

Comment: This is because you have a small data set, try to increase your data amount several times and you will see the difference. See updated post with tests

Comment: Thanks.. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

That you are spending 44 % on one block of the query plan does not necessarily mean the query is slow. However, as I have noticed, you have some other issues that probably affect any query speed.

- Your tables do not seem to be normalized. You have `VisitName` in both `Visitlookup` and `PatientVisit` tables.
- Your tables are missing primary keys and thus any indexes. If you add some constraints, the query plan looks very different. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb4db/1/0.
- You are using `float` type instead of some integer type for what seems to be identifying fields of the entities.
- The query itself looks fishy. Are you sure that the first two sub-queries need to be that, sub-queries?

Comment: The table structure is the client one. I will not have access to change it. Regarding the subqueries, I tried to join them using LEFT JOIN however i'm not able to get the desired result. So using two sub queries. DO you have any way to use instead of sub queries?

Comment: I had a look into the updates you made in my fiddle. The patientvisit cannot have a primary key on patient as it will have duplicates. However I can have foreign key in visit in patientvisit table.